# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая перед союзом "и"?

Tags: запятые

Как составить отчет и продажу товаров в общепите и рознице, и не бояться различных проверок.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под розницей. Продажа товаров в общепите по розничной цене?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение стилистически неудачно, т.к.нельзя составить продажу товаров, но  даже если не обращать внимание на смысл и исходить из структуры предложения, запятая не нужна, т.к. здесь однородные придаточные: **как составить отчёт и как не бояться проверок.**

Comment: Однородные инфинитивы, не придаточные, подчинительный союз же один. То есть обоснование ещё проще.

Comment: Я не понимаю, о чем вы. Союз может быть опущен. Здесь однородные придаточные.

Comment: Почему не одно? По смыслу — как сделать это и при этом это. Количество глаголов не определяет количество придаточных, это можно легко доказать. "Не бояться" связано по смыслу с "составить" (*составить так, чтобы не бояться*). Между однородными такого нет, однородность проявляется в независимости. Однородные придаточные можно было бы поменять местами.

Comment: Да там же не будет рассказываться, как не бояться. "Не бояться" связано с "составить". По смыслу один блок (придаточное).

Comment: Предложение стилистически неудачно. Нужно перестроить.

Comment: Не неудачно, а неверно. Думаю, "по продаже" исправляет проблему. Ну так что, согласны с вышесказанным? Или аргументируйте. Один глагол => одно придаточное — это неверно. Например: *Вася рассказал, как он шёл в магазин и увидел Петю* (глаголов два, а придаточное одно). В простых предложениях может быть несколько глаголов, и придаточные не исключение.

Comment: Я уже вам ответил.

Comment: Перестроили: *Как составить отчет по продаже товаров в общепите и рознице и не бояться различных проверок.* Глаголы связаны, ещё одно "как" не звучит.

Comment: Второй союз часто опускается.

Comment: Все равно предложение неудачно. Как можно составить отчет в рознице? Это, что, место?

Comment: И что, вы хотите сказать, что в придаточном не может быть двух глаголов? Что два глагола — два придаточных? Это вздор. Ну так исправил же. "Неудачно" и "неверно" — это разные вещи. Неудачное ещё можно применить.

Comment: Послушайте, я ничего такого не говорил. Читайте внимательно!

Comment: Ещё раз: почему не одно? Потому что часто опускается? Бред. Это не обоснование.

Comment: 1) Если однородные придаточные предложения прикрепляются к главному одним и тем же союзом, то этот союз может опускаться в одном или нескольких придаточных (но союз легко восстановить).

Ср.: Шацкий видел, /1 как последняя шлюпка вернулась к пароходу /2 и / матросы долго, мешая друг другу, подтягивали её на талях /3 (Паустовский). – Шацкий видел, /1 как последняя шлюпка вернулась к пароходу /2 и / как матросы долго, мешая друг другу, подтягивали её на талях /3.

Comment: А разве я говорил, что здесь одно придаточное?

Comment: Из этого не следует, что в данном предложении два придаточных. 1) Второе "как" не в тему. 2) Местами не меняется. 3) Второй глагол связан с первым. Это всё в пользу того, что одно придаточное.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже и сказали выше, запятая не нужна. Но лучше перестроить предложение:

**Как составить отчет и продажу товаров в общепите и рознице, не боясь различных проверок**.

Comment: Не-не, смысл в том, чтобы не бояться после, а не во время составления. Проверяют, когда отчёт уже составлен, а не во время составления.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так:

(1) СПП с придаточным **цели**

*Как составить отчет и организовать продажу товаров в общепите и рознице, **чтобы не бояться различных проверок.***

(2) Редактирование исходного **простого** предложения

*Как **составить** отчет и **организовать** продажу товаров в общепите и рознице и **при этом** **не бояться** различных проверок.*

Предложение односоставное **инфинитивное** с тремя **однородными** сказуемыми. Для связи используются **два союза И** и дополнительный структурный элемент ***при этом.*** Нужно соединить два сказуемых, а потом к ним присоединить третье.

Ввиду распространенности предложение без "при этом" сложно понимается, но все-таки лучше использовать СПП.

**Примечание**. ***Как*** (каким образом) – относительное (вопросительное) местоимение, придаточных здесь нет.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147830/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Но "не бояться" не соответствует "специальной речи".

Answer (score 1):

Второй (улучшенный) ответ

Редактирование: *Как **организовать**  отчет и **реализацию** товаров в общепите и рознице и не бояться различных проверок.*

Запятая не нужна.

**1. Грамматический анализ**

Это название статьи в **специальной** литературе, что видно по соответствующей **лексике** (см. словарь).

Предложение **простое**, осложненное **однородными** членами: двумя сказуемыми, двумя дополнениями и двумя обстоятельствами места. Связь **союзная**: союз И для каждой пары однородных членов.

Вид предложения — **односоставное инфинитивное**. Сказуемое: (как) организовать и не бояться,  относительное местоимение КАК общее, относится к обоим инфинитивам.

**Об инфинитивных предложениях:**  [Синтаксис современного  русского языка, стр. 92](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

**2. Правило Розенталя**

Знаки препинания соответствуют [правилу Розенталя, пункт 11](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

Если союз и **повторяется** в предложении не при однородных членах, то запятая между ними **не ставится**: *Рассмотреть планы и тезисы докладов и выступлений на научной конференции и своевременно напечатать их.*

**Приложение**

**РОЗНИЦА**, -ы; ж. **Спец.** Товар, продаваемый или покупаемый поштучно, в небольших количествах. Торговая р. Мелкая р. <В розницу, в зн. нареч. Поштучно, в небольших количествах (противоп.: оптом). Продавать оптом и в розницу. Торговать в розницу. Розничный, -ая, -ое. Р-ые цены. Р-ая продажа. Р-ые товары.

**ОБЩЕПИТ**, -а; м. **Офиц.** Система общественного питания, включающая столовые, кафе, рестораны и т.п. <Общепитовский; (разг.) общепитский, -ая, -ое. О-ая система. О-ая столовая.

**РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ**, св. и нсв. что. 1. Провести - проводить в жизнь, осуществить - осуществлять на практике. Р. свои творческие планы и замыслы. 2. **Продать - продавать**, обратить - обращать в деньги. Р. залежалый товар. Р. продукцию по завышенным ценам.  Реализация (см.).